# Sending JSON HTTP Get Request within Javascript File

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

From within a javascript file in my rails application: I want to send a JSON request to my application, which returns an array of strings, and capture that return value within a variable.

From the root of the application: the path to the request is: '/employers/get_unique_employer_names.json'

So If I'm in development mode: the full url would be:

http://localhost:3000/employers/get_unique_employer_names.json

Something like this but it doesn't work:

```
// app/assets/javascripts/application.js 
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function(){
  var array_of_names = get: '/employers/get_unique_employer_names.json'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have injected jquery

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/employers/get_unique_employer_names.json"
})
.done(function( data ) {
    console.log("here is you data", data);  
});
```

and same without jquery

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
       if(xmlhttp.status == 200){               
           console.log("Here is your data", xmlhttp.responseText);
       }           
       else {
           console.log('something else other than 200 was returned');
       }
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", "/employers/get_unique_employer_names.json", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Open console and check for your data

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I think I'm almost there.  Please see my updated question.  For some reason it is coming up undefined.

Comment: It is correct, but you have to put debugger right after `array_employer_names = data;` 

If you put outside `done` callback then debugger will be called before result of request returned. Ajax requests are asynchronous that is the reason of using `done` method. You can read about sync/async requests here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Comment: Also check network tab in inspector to debug whether your request sent without errors

Answer (score 0):

`array_employer_names` is undefined because it is defined in your js file, which make it unvisible from console. it's a scope thing.

you'll able the view it in your console if you change it to

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/employers/get_unique_employer_names.json"
})
.done(function( data ) {
    window.array_employer_names = data
});
```